# Managed Package Warning Message

Tags: managed-package

When I am trying to install the Managed package in my org i am getting an Warning  message

You’re installing a Non-Salesforce Application that is not authorized for distribution as part of Salesforce’s AppExchange Partner Program.

Answer (score 4):

Looks like the package you are Installing has not gone through [salesforce standard security review process](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Security_Review) .

Apps on the Salesforce [appexchange](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/) go through salesforce security review process .Salesforce does a strict security review to make sure the application is free from Security vulnerabilities and adhere to OWSAP security standards .

The package you are installing now , you are doing so with on own risk and hence salesforce is warning you .You might want to ask the vendor of the package about this .